# Bootstrap Carousel does not slide

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using the bootsrap carousel:

```
<header id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/fotografie1.JPG');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                    <p>hihihaio</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/fotografie1.JPG');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/fotografie1.JPG');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
         <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    </header>
```

The pictures are not sliding, also you can't click for going to the previous or next picture. I have the correct (updated) versions of  and  in my head. Also the following is in my head.

```
<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>

$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

I've looked for others with the same problem, and their solutions did not work with mine. When I open it in Google Chrome and use the element inspector I got these errors, what do they mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that JQuery is loaded before you use JQuery Javascript, such as Bootstrap.

Your code is fine.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd5hxmps/)

Right: (references JQuery after Jquery is loaded)

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Wrong: (references JQuery before JQuery is loaded)

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your HTML does not include jQuery which is required to run Bootstrap Javascript and other jQuery dependant components.

You have to include jQuery at the end of your body before including every other component like Bootstrap.js (see example Bootstrap template below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap stylesheet-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    YOUR CAROUSEL HERE (marked with class='carousel')

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap.js (Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed) -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>  
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000 //changes the speed
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```